# React Native ScrollView rerender all components

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

I have a problem with ScrollView in React Native.
I have a code with structure:

```
render(){
return (
    <ScrollView
      stickyHeaderIndices={[1]}
      refreshControl={
        <RefreshControl
          refreshing={this.props.mainScreen.loading}
          onRefresh={this.props.onMainScreenUpdate}
        />
      }>
      <MainScreenTopList />
      <View>
        <SegmentedControlIOS
          values={['LIST', 'ONE']}
          selectedIndex={this.props.mainScreen.tabsSelectedIndex}
          onChange={(event) => {
            this.props.setTabIndex(event.nativeEvent.selectedSegmentIndex);
          }}
        />
      </View>
      {this._renderSelectedBlock()}
    </ScrollView>
  );
}
```

When I switch SegmentedControl, all images and all blocks unmount and then mount again. I look this in `componentWillUnmount()` in `<MainScreenTopList />`, so why all my content start to jump. How can I stop unmount components in scrollview, not controlled by `<SegmentedControlIOS />`.

Comment: try adding style={{flex: 1}} in parent component!

Comment: nope, it does not make sense, the problem is in re-rendering MainScreenTopList component, which contain images. React unmount it first, and than mount again, so why i can't calculate image height once(on componentWillMount), sorry for my bad english